# Can I wrap a custom desktop application in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I would like to wrap a custom desktop application (don't have access to source code just the .exe and .msi) in a docker container from windows OS and share the image to my team to enable them access from windows OS. Could someone let me know if this is possible or please point me in the right direction (possibly a tutorial as I couldn't find it)?

Answer (score 0):

No, Docker does not run Windows binaries. The Docker for Windows products run Linux inside of a VM as the Docker host and all containers are Linux based.

Comment: Thank you BMitch. Makes more sense now